# How I can get a github actions runner token

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-runners

I want to create a VM and setup as self-hosted runner during my workflow. Right now, what blocks me is the lack of API that gives me Runner Token. If this exists, I could create the instance and register it as a runner, being able to use it in the next job.

Does anyone now a workaround to get the runner token?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Late Update

[Looks](https://github.community/t/api-to-generate-runners-token/16963/14) like they have finally created the runner api. See the API [specs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#self-hosted-runners) here.

[image: [POST] /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runners/registration-token]

They now also have [example snippets](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#create-a-registration-token-for-a-repository--code-samples) on how to do this. See the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297314/2089675) posted here for a complete example.

---

### Previous Answer

For now you have to create instances manually using the guide found [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/adding-self-hosted-runners).

According to a [github staff](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/API-to-generate-runners-token/m-p/39911#M4012), there is a plan to eventually add an api for generating the runner tokens, but didn't disclose a timeline of when this could happen.

> An API for this is on the roadmap. I don't have a timeline to share at
> the moment. But we'll be posting to the [**Changelog**](https://github.blog/changelog/) when this is
> available.
>
> And to clear up some of the confusion around PATs/runner tokens. The
> runner token provided via the UI is a temporary token that expires
> after 60 minutes. It only has the ability to register runners.
>
> PATs are not able to register runners.

Answer (score 6):

The API for creating the Registration Token is available already:

- [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#create-a-registration-token-for-a-repository) you can read how to create the one for the repository level
- And [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#create-a-registration-token-for-an-organization) - for the organization level

Using the following JavaScript code, you can create the GitHub Registration Token inside of your GitHub Action:

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

async function getRegistrationToken() {
  const githubToken = core.getInput('github_token'); // the GitHub Secret Token provided as an input of your GitHub Action using ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  const octokit = github.getOctokit(githubToken);

  const response = await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runners/registration-token', {
    owner: github.context.repo.owner, // the value is taken from the environment variable GITHUB_REPOSITORY which is provided by the GitHub Action during runtime
    repo: github.context.repo.repo, // the value is taken from the environment variable GITHUB_REPOSITORY which is provided by the GitHub Action during runtime
  });

  return response.data.token;
}

module.exports = {
  getRegistrationToken,
};
```

Comment: BTW: If you're interested, I'm working on the GitHub Action for creating an on-demand AWS EC2 instance and register it as a self-hosted GitHub Actions runner. It's still in progress but will be ready soon: https://github.com/machulav/aws-github-runner. So feel free to follow.

Comment: I tried to use the above solution in my Github Action but unfortulately it is erroring out with - Error: Resource not accessible by integration - https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners#create-a-registration-token-for-a-repository.

I think the prob here is permsissons for the GITHUB_TOKEN in the actions but is there a way to assign permissions to default token ?